# How to populate foreign key in table Spring + Hibernate + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, one-to-one

I want make a case, when user is authenticated by Spring Security and then he fill adres form I would like to automatically updated a foreign key column "adres_id" in user table. Please give me a tip how implement this in the most popular way

I how somethig like this

**Address Table:**
[image: Address Table]

**User Table:**
[image: User Table]

**Adres**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="adres")
public class Adres {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    int id;

    @Column(name="country", nullable=false)
    private String country;
    private String street;
    private String postcode;
    private String telephone;
    private String pesel;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="adres")
    private User user;




    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }
    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getPesel() {
        return pesel;
    }
    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return postcode;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    int id;

    @Column(name="username", nullable=false)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Boolean enabled;



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Adres adres;


    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**AdresDAO**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AdresDAOImpl implements AdresDAO{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addAdres(Adres adres) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(adres);
    }

    public List<Adres> listAdres() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Adres order by id").list();
    }

    public void removeAdres(int id) {
        Adres adres = (Adres) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Adres.class, id);
        if (null != adres) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(adres);
        }

    }
    public Adres getAdres(int id) {

        return (Adres)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Adres.class, id);
    }

  public void editAdres(Adres adres) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(adres);
    }



}
```

**AdresService**

```
@Service
public class AdresServiceImpl implements AdresService{

    @Autowired
    AdresDAO adresDAO;



    @Transactional
    public void addAdres(Adres adres) {
        adresDAO.addAdres(adres);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void editAdres(Adres adres) {
        adresDAO.editAdres(adres);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Adres> listAdres() {

        return adresDAO.listAdres();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeAdres(int id) {
        adresDAO.removeAdres(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Adres getAdres(int id) {
        return adresDAO.getAdres(id);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` unidirectional relation between `User` and `Address` if `Address` object does not supposed to know about its owner (generally it does not). I would prefer user id in `Address` table if a `User` have more than one `Address` (one-to-many relation).

But for your question you may design like that,

```
public class User{
    ...
    @OneToOne(CascadeType.REMOVE)//this is for to remove address when user is removed
    @JoinColumn(name="HOME_ADDRESS_ID")
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    int id;

    @Column(name="country", nullable=false)
    private String country;
    private String street;
    private String postcode;
    private String telephone;
    private String pesel;

    //no user object here

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I design it like you show me but it still not resolve my problem. When I fill address object it populate a "Address" table and i have a foreign key HOME_ADDRESS_ID in my "User" table but it don't have a value. I want to have this same value of "id" in "Address" table and "HOME_ADDRESS_ID" in "User" table. How to implemnt it ?

Comment: So first save your address, then set this address to user's address like user.setAddress(mySavedNewAddress) then you will see address id in user table.

Comment: Actually after jpa did its work it will automatically update your address object's id but be sure that your newly created address has an id after this operation.

Comment: Yeaa exactly ! Big thanks, this is what I meant. At the beginning I was in mistake, becouse I thinking a foreign key upgraded automatically by using JPA without any setters

Comment: :) nice to hear that.